# skip header line and replace string in text file in batch script

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off 
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
 for /r %f in (xis_*) do  More +1 %~nxf >> No_header_%~nxf
    set "search=:20:"
    set "replace={:20:"
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type (No_header*.txt) ^& break ^> (No_header_*.txt) ') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
        >>No_header*.txt echo(!line!
        endlocal
    )
```

I am trying to skip the header line in a text file and replace `:20:` with `{:20:`. I have written and have almost achieved my goal.

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter to figure out which line you are on, and then perform your actions based on that.

Something like:

```
SET /A MYCOUNT=0

for ... do (
  SET /A MYCOUNT+=1
  IF %MYCOUNT% GTR 1 (
    ' Do stuff  
  )
)
```